# How to share event object in community

Tags: community, event

Are there any options to share events in community. I'd like to keep track of customer events but did not find the solution to expose events into community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Event object isn't available to portal users except in partner portals. The only way to make Events visible to them is to create a custom "mirror" object of Events using a trigger and then expose the custom object to Portal Users. For more on what objects are visible by license type see this page on [Community User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US).